# How to export a specific selection of references from Mendeley

Tags: reference, mendeley

I  am contributing to a book, and I used Mendeley to manage the bibliography of my chapter. Now the editor has asked me to provide my list of references in a file format compatible with Zotero.

I can easily export the Mendeley collection as a .RIS file and import it to Zotero using this [procedure](https://catherinepope.com/how-to-import-your-mendeley-library-into-zotero/), but I would not like to export the whole collection (more than 2000 entries), neither select the references manually one by one (about 100).

Is there a way I can automatically select the bibliography I used for my chapter in the Mendeley Desktop and then export it in a unique .RIS file?

I am using Mendeley Desktop version 1.18 on a Windows 8 machine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success two ways:

1. Create a folder and place all the items that were cited in the book chapter in that folder. Select the folder, highlight the records [Ctrl+A], then export those cites as the RIS file to upload to Zotero.
2. Tag the used citations with a unique tag, select those records [Ctrl+A], and then export that collection as the RIS file.

Comment: Thanks Suzi, this would not avoid to still deal with the references one by one, but apparently there is not a way to make Mendeley select only the references used in a document to then export only that selection. Both putting the references in a folder, and tagging them imply to operate manually in a one by one sequence, which is what I was trying to avoid. I accept your answer anyway, since there is no way to do what I actually wanted to do. Maybe the Mendeley developers will read this one day...